Unabe to start gazebo topics
Details
I want to simulate a custom SLAM implementation on a monocular robot in gazebo. For that I need access to the latest frame seen by the robot in the gazebo world. I see two was of achieving that:

Use the save enabled="true" feature of the camera sensor
Advertise a topic from the (camera) sensor and subscribe to it to receive the image messages

What I have tried

I have tried the camera_save tutorial but no images are saved to the specified directory
I have tried manaully creating a camera sensor with a topic but the topic is not created:

<model name='camera'>
    <static>true</static>
    <pose>-1 0 2 0 1 0</pose>
    <link name='link'>
        <visual name='visual'>
            <geometry>
                <box>
                    <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
                </box>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <sensor name='my_camera' type='camera'>
            <topic>/my_world/my_camera</topic>
            <camera>
                <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <width>1920</width>
                    <height>1080</height>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.1</near>
                    <far>100</far>
                </clip>
                <save enabled="true">
                    <path>/tmp/camera</path>
                </save>
            </camera>
            <always_on>1</always_on>
            <update_rate>10</update_rate>
        </sensor>
    </link>
</model>

output of gz topic -l does not show the specified topic:
/clock
/gazebo/resource_paths
/gui/camera/pose
/gui/currently_tracked
/gui/track
/stats
/world/default/clock
/world/default/dynamic_pose/info
/world/default/pose/info
/world/default/scene/deletion
/world/default/scene/info
/world/default/state
/world/default/stats
/world/default/light_config
/world/default/material_color


Note: subscribing to the above topics work just fine


I tried the segmentation camera tutorial but the segmentation topic is not created as mentioned in point (2)
I have tried creating a scene using the gazebo c++ API as shown in the save_images example and it works perfectly fine

System Info
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Gazebo Sim, version 8.7.0
gz-common6
gz-math8
gz-utils3
gz-msgs11
gz-transport14
Side Note
Whenever I run a gz command or run a binary that uses the gazebo c++ API, the following error logs are printed every single time:
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/time.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/header.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/vector3d.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/quaternion.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pose.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/actor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/actuators.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sensor_noise.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/air_pressure_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/air_speed.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/air_speed_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/altimeter.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/altimeter_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/vector2d.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/axis_aligned_2d_box.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/annotated_axis_aligned_2d_box.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/annotated_axis_aligned_2d_box_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/oriented_3d_box.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/annotated_oriented_3d_box.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/annotated_oriented_3d_box_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/color.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/any.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/atmosphere.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/axis.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/axis_aligned_box.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/battery.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/battery_state.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/boolean.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/boxgeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/bytes.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/camera_cmd.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/camera_info.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/camera_lens.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/distortion.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/double.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/image.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/lens.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/camerasensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/cameratrack.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/capsulegeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/cessna.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/clock.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/cmd_vel2d.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/conegeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/cylindergeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/ellipsoidgeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/heightmapgeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/imagegeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/meshgeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/planegeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/polylinegeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/spheregeom.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/geometry.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/friction.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/surface.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/material.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/plugin.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/visual.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/collision.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/wrench.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint_wrench.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/contact.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/contacts.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/contactsensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:4201] Invalid proto descriptor for file "gz/msgs/spherical_coordinates.proto":
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:4204]   gz/msgs/spherical_coordinates.proto: A file with this name is already in the pool.
DynamicFactory(). Unable to place descriptors from [/usr/share/gz/protos/gz-msgs10.gz_desc] in the descriptor pool
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/data_load_options.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dataframe.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/density.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/diagnostics.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/discovery.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/double_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/duration.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dvl_kinematic_estimate.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dvl_range_estimate.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dvl_beam_state.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dvl_tracking_target.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/dvl_velocity_tracking.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/empty.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/light.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/gps_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/imu_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/lidar_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/logical_camera_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/magnetometer_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/inertial.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/float.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/stringmsg.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/particle_emitter.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/projector.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/link.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/model.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity_factory.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity_factory_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity_plugin_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity_wrench.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/entity_wrench_map.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/float_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/fluid.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/fluid_pressure.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/fog.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/version.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/version_range.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/versioned_name.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/fuel_metadata.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/gps.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/track_visual.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:4201] Invalid proto descriptor for file "gz/msgs/gui_camera.proto":
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:4204]   gz/msgs/gui_camera.proto: A file with this name is already in the pool.
DynamicFactory(). Unable to place descriptors from [/usr/share/gz/protos/gz-msgs10.gz_desc] in the descriptor pool
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/gui.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/hydra.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/imu.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/int32.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/int32_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/int64.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/int64_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint_animation.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pid.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint_cmd.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint_trajectory_point.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joint_trajectory.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joy.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/joystick.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/laserscan.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/link_data.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/log_control.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/log_playback_control.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/log_playback_stats.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/log_status.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/logical_camera_image.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/magnetometer.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/marker.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/marker_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/material_color.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/model_configuration.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/model_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/navsat.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/navsat_sensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/occupancy_grid.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/twist.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/odometry.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pose_with_covariance.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/twist_with_covariance.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/odometry_with_covariance.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pose_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/stringmsg_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/web_request.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/world_stats.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/packet.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/param.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/param_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: google/protobuf/any.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter_declaration.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter_declarations.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter_error.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter_name.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/parameter_value.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/particle_emitter_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/performance_sensor_metrics.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/physics.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/plugin_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pointcloud.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pointcloud_packed.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pose_animation.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/pose_trajectory.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/propagation_particle.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/propagation_grid.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/publish.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/publishers.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/raysensor.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/request.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/response.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/rest_login.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/rest_logout.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/rest_post.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/rest_response.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/road.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sky.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/scene.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sdf_generator_config.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/selection.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sensor_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/serialized.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/serialized_map.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/server_control.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/shadows.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sim_event.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/sonar.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/statistic.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/subscribe.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/tactile.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/test.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/topic_info.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/uint32.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/uint32_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/uint64.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/uint64_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/undo_redo.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/world_reset.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/world_control.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/user_cmd.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/user_cmd_stats.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/video_record.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/visual_v.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/wheel_slip_parameters_cmd.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/wind.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/wireless_node.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/wireless_nodes.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/world_control_state.proto
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:121] File already exists in database: gz/msgs/world_modify.proto

Although the error logs seem to be unrelated to the issue I am facing since the c++ pubsub example works just fine.

Do I need to add a plugin?

Have a look at the debug messages by running gazebo with -v 4 flag, i.e. gz sim -v 4 my_world.sdf. It should show debug output for the plugin being loaded as well as which topics is created.
Also try the camera_sensor demo world, which should work...

I did not read the camera_sensor example properly
Turns out my suspicion was correct and I just need to add the sensor plugin:
        <plugin filename="gz-sim-sensors-system" name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
            <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
        </plugin>

Thanks a lot!
